# Objective-C Storyboards Segue - Passing data from destination back to sourceViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I currently have two view controllers and I linked them up via storyboard segue(navigation controller). When the user presses a button on the first view, the screen goes to the second view. In the second view, there are text fields so that the user can edit the detailed information. When I press the back navigation button, how can I pass that detailed information from the second view controller back to the first view controller?

I use this code to send data from the first view controller to the second view controller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [segue sourceViewController];
    [settingsViewController setAddressString:[self addressString]];
    NSLog(@"Settings address string of SettingsViewController to: %@", [self addressString]);
}
```

The only way I can think of right now of passing the data from the second view controller to the first view controller is to override the `viewWillDisappear` method of the second view controller. But is there a way that works by using the segue method? And what is the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use delegation. 
In your second view controller header file you'll have to create a delegate method.

```
@protocol SettingsDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)userHasCompletedSettings:(NSArray *)userSettings;
@end 

@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController
@property id<SettingsDelegate>delegate;
// Any other properties you have
@end
```

In your first view controller when calling your segue you set the delegate to self.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [segue sourceViewController];
    [settingsViewController setAddressString:[self addressString]];
    NSLog(@"Settings address string of SettingsViewController to: %@", [self addressString]);
    settingsViewController.delegate = self;
}
```

In your second view controller you need to call the method. You can implement your own Back button so that you can set up an IBAction to call your delegate method.

```
- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // Package up your settings details in the array
    [self userHasCompletedSettings:arrayOfMySettings];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

You also need to set up the method for the backButtonPressed action to call on the first view controller.

```
-(void)userHasCompletedSettings:(NSArray *)userSettings
{
    // Do what you need to do with the settings.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the detail controller a reference to the master view controller (i.e. `self`), and let it call methods to set the results.

For example, you can do this:

```
@interface MasterController : UIViewController
-(void)updateAddressString:(NSString*) address;
@end

@interface DetailController : UIViewController
-(void)setAddressString:(NSString*) address;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) MasterController *master;
@end
```

Now you can write this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [segue sourceViewController];
    [settingsViewController setAddressString:[self addressString]];
    [settingsViewController setMaster:self];
    NSLog(@"Settings address string of SettingsViewController to: %@", [self addressString]);
}
```

When the `DetailController` needs to update the address in the master, it does this:

```
[_master updateAddressString:updatedAddress];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class which represents your model object with properties that correspond to fields in SettingsViewController.

You create it and pass to your SettingsViewController in prepareForSegue method and assign it to property/ivar of the current viewController. So you have a model object instance shared between two viewControllers. When you enter information into fields - assign it to your custom model object properties. 
Your first viewContoller can get information from properties of the shared model object.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Do you mean something like a singleton model object?

Comment: It may be singleton or simple object, but instance of it should be shared across two viewControllers (ex: @property (strong, nonatomic) CustomModelObject *obj;) It must not be released or recreated when you perform segue or go back.